# What is the difference between 神社, お寺 and お宮?

Tags: word-choice, words, kanji-choice

All of them mean "shrine" or "temple", but what is the difference between all of them ?

Comment: There is also a "jingu", 神宮, what about that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

神社 is a generic word for a Shinto shrine.

お宮 is another word for 神社, but a little more respectful.

お寺 is a Buddhist temple.

Comment: I would say お宮 is more colloquial/casual or even friendly (that does not mean it's less respectful). People sometimes even say お宮さん but never 神社さん.